# After setting loadonce to false multiple search for jqgrid , it is not loading the searched data. It is reloading the grid with all the data

Tags: jqgrid

After setting loadonce to false multiple search for jqgrid ,  it is not loading the searched data. It is reloading the grid with all the data.

Comment: I want to make the advanced search fill the grid with the searched data

Answer (score 1):

The server should returns **different data** depend on whether you use `loadonce: true` or default `loadonce: false` option. It seems that your server part provide incorrect data for `loadonce: false`.

For understanding. jqGrid send to server some parameters. It's default names are `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord`, `_search` and additional parameters in case of filtering. In case of Advanced Searching its parameter `filters`.

To implement correctly server part in case of usage `loadonce: true` one need just use `sidx` and `sord` input parameters and returns **all data** which need be just sorted corresponds to values of `sidx` and `sord` parameters.

To implement correctly server part in case of usage `loadonce: false` you need implement more sophisticated logic on the server side. The server should filter the data based on `filters` parameter (if `_search` is set), the results of filtering should be sorted by `sidx` and `sord` and the final results have to be divided on pages of size `rows` and the page specified by `page` parameter should be returned to the server. So only **one page** of filtered data should be returned by the server. **In other words you have to implement filtering, sorting and paging of data on the server side if you don't want to use `loadonce: true`.**

[The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) provides an example of such implementation on ASP.NET MVC.